# Buildbot synchronization between builders 0.9.x

Tags: buildbot

My question boils down to a specific use case.

**Simple scenario with two builders:**

- Start one builder which is something like a server
- When server is built and is running, notify clients that they can connect
- Run all tests for the client
- ...
- Kill the server
- ...

**Is there a built in way to notify second build it can start/continue to run?**

I can have another builder which is started parallel to the server builder and check if server is in a specific state and if it is then it triggers a scheduler for a client, but as the build configuration will grow, build graph would become needlessly too big and this approach also requires some custom implementation (depending on OS and other requirements) which pollute CI process and which I would prefer not to (ab)use.

**Additionally is there a built in way/better approach to kill a server builder from client builder without using buildbot REST API?**

If somebody has a link to a public repo which has similar use case I would also appreciate it.

Comment: You could trigger the client build at the end of the server build

Comment: @yhager: I've edited question with situation that server has to be running, but if server is running that means that execution of that builder is frozen so I can't trigger client build. Currently I'm handling this situation with parallel builder on the same worker that triggers client builder on another worker. I haven't yet gave answer here since I'm not entirely sure this should be appropriate solution.

Comment: I would then make the server a "service" or a "daemon". This way you woul call 'start' on it from the builder, then trigger the client(s), and then call 'stop' on the server..

Comment: @yhager: Let's just say this is impossible for a server/service in this case since starting/stopping does not allow me to know when he is actually fully up and running, so daemonizing it doesn't solve this issue. I'm also not allowed to modify sources.